# Docker stack and Doctrine migration

Tags: php, symfony, docker, doctrine

I have a simple docker stack with three containers : a mysql one, a php-fpm one and a nginx.

I just want to be able to execute my doctrine migrations and a symfony command every time my container is created.

Currently, i got an error like : "entrypoint.sh not found" when i type **docker logs #myphpcontainername#** after building and docker-compose up -d 'ing.

My php-fpm docker file :

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libpq-dev git libicu-dev libxml2-dev \
......

RUN curl --insecure https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar -o /usr/bin/composer && chmod +x /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /var/www/symfony

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ['/entrypoint.sh']
```

And my entrypoint.sh, located at the same place than my Dockerfile :

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

sleep 5
php /var/www/symfony/bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction --allow-no-migration

exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to make that file executable

```
RUN chmod 0700 entrypoint.sh
```

or it should be

```
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```

Take a look at this post that has a good explanation
https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ADD . /var/www/symfony
WORKDIR /var/www/symfony

RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
...
CMD ["/var/www/symfony/entrypoint.sh"]
```